# trouble understanding count.multiple and simplify in igraph

Tags: r, matrix, igraph

I am working with network data and have come across an odd (or at least I didn't expect it) behavior with `count.multiple` in the `igraph` package in R.

```
library(igraph)
library(plyr)

df <- data.frame( sender = c( "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c","c","d" ),
              receiver = c( "b", "b", "b", "c", "a", "d", "d", "a" ) )
```

What I want is to count up all of the edges and use the multiples as a weight.

when I do `ddply(df, .(sender, receiver), "nrow")` my results are:

```
  sender receiver nrow
1      a        b    3
2      b        a    1
3      b        c    1
4      c        d    2
5      d        a    1
```

Which is what I would expect.

However, I cannot reproduce this using igraph's `count.multiple`, which is what I expected to do this within igraph

```
df.graph <- graph.edgelist(as.matrix(df))
E(df.graph)$weight <- count.multiple(df.graph)
```

`E(df.graph)$weight` produces:

```
3 3 3 1 1 2 2 1
```

I then used the `simplify` command:

```
df.graph <- simplify(df.graph)
```

which produces

```
9 1 1 4 1
```

I get what is going on here, simplify is just adding the weights, but I don't understand why/when this would be used as opposed to what `ddply` is doing..?

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behaviour of `simplify` is to add the weights of multiple edges.

To avoid double counting, you can set the initial weights to 1

```
g <- graph.edgelist(as.matrix(df))
E(g)$weight <- 1
g <- simplify( g )
E(g)$weight
```

or change the way they are aggregated.

```
g <- graph.edgelist(as.matrix(df))
E(g)$weight <- count.multiple(g)
g <- simplify( g, edge.attr.comb = list(weight=max, name="concat", "ignore") )
E(g)$weight
```

Comment: so doing `count.multiple` then `simplify` is redundant?

Comment: Yes: in the example, `count.multiple` assigns the weight 3 to the  a→b edges, but there are still three of them; `simplify` then adds those weights, resulting in a total weight of 9. We end up with the square of the desired weight.